# Reinstalling Yum

Tags: linux

Okay - I'm having a real hard time warming up to linux. I am desperately trying to install yum, which is supposed to come with Fedora Core 6, but apparently it didn't for me.

I have python 2.4.1, a little reading shows yum 3.0.1 is the version for me. So I get it, untar it, and use the make command as instructed.

Now when I use a yum command, I get

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Oct  1 2006, 17:59:36) 
[GCC 4.1.1 20060928 (Red Hat 4.1.1-28)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq
```

Okay? That was worthless.  there is no yum? or Python is missing a module? Probably no yum because missing the module, but which one? Some one says "Install it from a rpm" - well, how do I do that? I'm thinking I need to uninstall yum?

**UPDATE** It looks like Network Solutions VPS is trying to stimulate support revenue by going out of their way to provide the most out of date configuration they can. Not only are they running FC6 - but YUM was somehow removed? Upon trying to install it, I received this...

```
warning: yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 4f2a6fd2
6fd2error: F
error: Failed dependencies:
python-elementtree is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
python-sqlite is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
rpm-python is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
urlgrabber is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch
yum-metadata-parser is needed by yum-3.0.6-1.fc6.noarch[root@02
```

Theoretically, if I install all of these packages, it will work, right?. Should I be concerned about the NOKEY?

Comment: **WHY** are you installing Fedora Core 6 to experiment with Linux? They're on version **12** by now.

Comment: This was the default OS for Network Solutions VPS. I wondered the same thing, but I think they're just lazy. PHP is out of date as well. I was hoping that once I got yum installed, it would be easier to install and update my other programs..at least I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know why you are using such an outdated version of Fedora but if you want to install YUM on it this is how you would do it.

Find this RPM as it is the one for FC6.
yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm

Then run this command as root in the directory where you downloaded the RPM.

rpm -Uvh yum-3.0-6.noarch.rpm

Comment: THanks, the ultimate answer is to upgrade to the latest version of linux

Answer (score 0):

OK.  It sounds like what you've done is manually install some software package (perhaps python) in such a way that it supersedes the OS-provided one.

It also sounds like you are just starting out, so if that is the case I recommend you go get a current version of Fedora -- Fedora churns pretty quickly and I don't think Fedora Core 6 is still supported, so even if you do get yum working, there are no mirrors around to do installs from.

Answer (score 0):

Nunya's answer is dead right.  On all counts.  It's really not advisable to using something as old as Fedora Core 6 and it's going to be difficult to find the rpm unless you have some old FC6 install media lying around.

If you're going ahead with the manual rebuild anyway (sounds like a world of pain) then you should probably pull the source rpm[1] and do a rebuild of the package[2].

Really, though, unless you've got some pressing need to run FC6 you should avoid doing this and go with a more recent release.

1. http://yum.baseurl.org/download/3.0/
2. You should set up a non-root build environment, then use the "rpmbuild" tool to create an RPM from either the .src.rpm or else the .tgz sources.

mkdir -p ~/rpm//{SOURCES,SPECS,BUILD,SRPMS,RPMS/{i386,athlon,i486,i586,i686,noarch}}

vi ~/.rpmmacros

```
%_topdir /absolute/path/to/rpm/directory/created/in/previous/step
```

rpm -ivh yum-3.0.6-1.src.rpm
(can actually skip the manual download and do that in one step "rpm -ivh http://yum.baseurl.org/download/3.0/yum-3.0.6-1.src.rpm" )

cd ~/rpm/SPECS

rpmbuild -bb yum-3.0.6-1.src.rpm

Assuming no errors reported during this build you can then

cd ../RPMS/noarch; ls

And behold a beautiful new yum-3.0.6-1.noarch.rpm which can be installed with:

rpm -ivh yum-3.0.6-1.noarch.rpm

If it squeaks about no keys or some such then you can (perform the further ill-advised step from a security standpoint) ignore that warning with

rpm -ivh --nosignature yum-3.0.6-1.noarch.rpm